# ‘tomorrow’ defined as @sys.date entity not setting the alarm for next day

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

I’m using [API.AI](http://api.ai) for setting alarms using voice assistant and for that I have made an Intent named ‘Set alarm’ and have defined various user expressions one of which is ‘Set an alarm at time tomorrow’ in which ‘time’ is defined as `@sys.time` entity whereas ‘tomorrow’ is defined as `@sys.date` entity.

Though `@sys.time` is setting the time quite well and appropriately but `@sys.date` is just showing the correct value of date like ‘2017-08-29’ but is unable to set the alarm for tomorrow.

For example when I am saying ‘Set an alarm at 2pm tomorrow’, it is setting the alarm for 2pm today and not tomorrow.

Here’s a bit of code:

```
if (entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray().size() != 0) {
    createAlarm("", Integer.valueOf(entry.getValue().toString().substring(2, 4)), Integer.valueOf(entry.getValue().toString().substring(5, 7)));
    hResponse.setText("Alarm set successfully!");
    tts.speak("Alarm set successfully!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "no time parameter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

How can I achieve the desired result which is setting alarm for tomorrow when I say set it for tomorrow?

Answer (score 1):

API.AI sends @sys.date and @sys.time parameters as ISO-8601 strings.  I'd recommend checking how you're parsing your the date and time strings coming from API.AI and to use a datetime library from your platform of choice to avoid making mistakes with date parsing. ([time and date entity docs](https://api.ai/docs/reference/system-entities))

To make sure your webhook is always sent both the time and date you may want to make them both [required parameters](https://api.ai/docs/actions-and-parameters#the_parameter_table).  Make sure to setup a prompt for each required parameter (i.e. "What time would you like to set the alarm for?")

Comment: I want to make one thing clear here.I’m using Common Intents: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#CreateAlarm for Creating an alarm. My code is same as in the link. Now, if user says “Set an alarm at 5:30 pm tomorrow.” Can API.AI set the alarm itself for tomorrow at 5:30 pm or will it set it at 5:30 pm the same day? I hope you got my question.

Comment: Android Intents and API.AI intents are completely separate constructs.  Sorry for the confusion.  API.AI's definition of intent: https://api.ai/docs/intents

Comment: I understand that Android and API.AI intents are different. I just want to make above asked query clear. Please answer that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Android intent for creating alarams, I'd recommend asking a separate question if you need help creating an Android intent that sets an alarm.

Comment: I have the code for creating alarms what I want to know here is related with API.AI which is: If user says “Set an alarm at 5:30 pm tomorrow.” Can API.AI set the alarm itself for tomorrow at 5:30 pm or will it set it at 5:30 pm the same day?

Comment: I'd recommend testing with API.AI to make sure it adheres to the specific use cases you're needing.  API.AI parameter \@sys.time will only provide a time and \@sys.date will only provide a date.  If the user only provides a time and \@sys.date is not a required parameter no date will be provided by API.AI.  If you're interested in a date and time you might want to look at the \@sys.date-time entity, documentation is here: https://api.ai/docs/reference/system-entities#date-en